# PHP - Iterate Though Additonial XML Node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am working with the following XML response structure:

```
<CompressedVehicles>
<F>
<RS> 
<R>
    <VS>
        <V />
        <V />
    </VS>
</R>
<R>
    <VS>
        <V />
        <V />
    </VS>
</R>
</RS>
</F>
</CompressedVehicles>
```

So far, with guidance from a fellow Stack Overflow member, I was able to construct a working JSON output based on the following PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$xml  = simplexml_load_file( 'inventory.xml' );
$CompressedVehicles = $xml->CompressedVehicles;

$attributes = array();
foreach( $CompressedVehicles->F->attributes() as $key => $val )
{
    $attributes[$key] = $val->__toString();
}

$data = array();
foreach( $CompressedVehicles->F->RS->R->VS->V as $vehicle )
{
    $line = array();
    foreach( $vehicle->attributes() as $key => $val )
{
    $line[$attributes[$key]] = $val->__toString();
}
$data[] = $line;
}

$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
```

This only iterates through a single `<R>` node before completion. How can I now append the code to iterate through each `<R>` node as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: don't point it directly into `V`, cut it to each `R`, so nest another loop, first loop until `R` first, then each piece of `R` then point to `VS->V`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're directly going to `$CompressedVehicles->F->RS->R->VS->V`, just modify it to loop each `<R>` node:

```
foreach( $CompressedVehicles->F->RS->R as $r )
{
```

This iterate to each `<R>`.

Then for each `<R>`, add another nest for the `$vehicle`:

```
foreach($r->VS->V as $vehicle) 
{
// rest of your code
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I stared and messed with it for over an hour and missed something that simple.

Comment: @proph3t sure glad this helped